# Is "This is from xxx" correct usage?

Tags: greetings, telephone

I placed a phone call and introduced myself this way: "Hi, This is from " and a coworker pointed out that the sentence is grammatically wrong.

While I understand that it sounds a bit weird, I'm wondering if it is entirely wrong. Is it? If yes, What are alternative correct usages that do not require me to provide my name?

Comment: "This is from ..." is still found in some geographies. Could be local influence or a vestige of something long forgotten.

Comment: Probably explains why I'm used to it, because I did not learn English in the United States. I do not know where I picked this up and I want to look into it. Do you have any pointers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In a phone call "this" usually refers to the speaker, so saying "this is from X" is kind of weird.  All of the following are normal:

- This is Name from Company.
- This is Name.
- I'm calling from Company.

Since you don't want to give your name, I recommend the last of these.

Comment: You could even say "I am from..." rather than "This is from...".

Comment: If "this" refers to the speaker, isn't saying "this is from X" similar to "I am from X"? I completely realize it sounds weird but is there a specific rule that says it is wrong? Thanks for the alternatives. They are a lot better than what I came up with.

Comment: @Bhaktavatsalam: There's nothing specifically making it "wrong". It's just that when you say *"This is John"*, you mean *"The person calling (me) is John"*. When you say *"This is from John"* you mean *"This* **call** *is from John"*. Anglophones aren't prissy about pushing themselves into the background like that, so we usually use the first version. If you were calling a Japanese company and expected it to be answered by a receptionist who would then transfer to whoever you want to speak to, the second version might actually be seen as "ultra-polite/empathic" (that's how *she* sees it).

Comment: @Bhaktavatsalam Nallanthighal, Yes, "this" refers to the speaker but the function is different from "I". If I say "This is mustafa", it reads as "the person who is talking on the phone  is mustafa. So, this=the person who is talking on the phone

Comment: What about using `This is *Company*` or `Company here` or `Good morning from Company`?

Comment: @Stephen: It would be *very* unusual to introduce yourself on the phone by saying *"This is [company]"*. I suppose if you were, say, Bill Gates, you might say *"This is Microsoft"*, but personally I'd probably just hang up if some underling came on like that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers that would be very unusual, yes.  I did experience it once, though -- I had called 911 and then hung up immediately (because somebody else was already through to them), and they called back starting with "this is 911; you called?".  In that case, though, the individual operator is completely unimportant, so "911" probably takes on name qualities.

Comment: I think it's company to ANSWER the phone with a company name. Like, "Hello, this is Joe's Pizza" is pretty routine. If I called a business's general line and someone answered, "This is Bob", I'd tend to think I'd gotten someone's home rather than a business. But when you call someone else, you normally say, "This is Bob Smith from Acme Company". Still, "This is Acme Company, calling about your recent service problem ..." is not uncommon.

Comment: @Jay: Perhaps there's a transatlantic difference there. In the UK, it's pretty much "industry standard" that people who call in a business/sales context always say something along the lines of *"This is [name] from [company]"*. But as you say, people at work answering phones accessible to the general public invariably give the company name first - sometimes followed by their own name (depending partly on what kind of job they're in).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Oh, I agree that "This is Bob Smith from Acme Company" is perhaps the most common way to announce yourself. But when you call a company and they answer the phone -- and maybe this is different in the US then the UK -- it's pretty common for them to just say, "Hello, Joe's Pizza". If you're calling a public line, you probably don't care who the individual is answer, you just want the company. Very busy places sometimes just say the company name, like "Joe's Pizza".

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to introduce yourself you can say

> May I speak with xxx?

Comment: Which may be answered with "who's calling?", and we're back to the original problem.

Comment: Arises, not arouses :)

Comment: @ jwpat7, thank you, I will edit. :)

Comment: @jwpat7: It might arouse, depending on who is calling. :-)

Comment: too late to edit. wish one could edit any time.

Comment: haha. There is the issue Monica Cellio pointed out. Also, there is the issue that I do not know who I am speaking to...

Answer (score 0):

"This is from ..." definitely sounds strange.

In a sentence like, "This is Bob", you can use the word "this" to refer to yourself. But this is really only appropriate when you are connecting "this" to your name or a few other cases where you are identifying yourself, like "This is I" (or as most people incorrectly say it, "This is me"). Otherwise, you should refer to yourself as "I" or "me" or use your name. Don't refer to yourself as "this". If you want to, for example, say that you are the owner of the green car, you would say, "I own the green car", not "This owns the green car." Or you announce yourself by saying, "I am here!", not "This is here!" Etc.

A little thought will show that a special case is required when giving your name. Otherwise, what will you link it to? Saying, "Bob is Bob" is recursive and uninformative. Of course you could say "I am Bob", but in the context of introducing yourself on the phone, you're trying to identify who the caller is rather than just identify yourself.

All that said, if you said, "Hi, this call is from Acme Company ..." I don't think anyone would question it. That is, saying "this call" makes "this" refer to the event rather than to yourself, and thus eliminates the strangeness of the pronoun use.

And regardless of all of that, it's generally considered polite to give your name, like, "This is Bob from Acme Company." Just saying, "This is Acme Company calling" sounds very impersonal.